# WSO2 IS OAuth2 Resource owner password - getting access token

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, passwords, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to obtain oauth token from WSO2 identity server:

```
curl -v  -X POST -u "GIHAZzRMGNnm3X8XGMwZVoCe2hUa:Uf4wAlQWufaTk320Se2emnJVgvca" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=myemail@shan.com&password=mypwd" https://localhost:9449/oauth2/token
```

The response is
    {"error":"server_error","error_description":"Error when issuing the access token"}

The exception at the server

> TID[-1234] [IS] [2015-08-08 11:53:15,692] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} - Error when issuing the access token. org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.issue(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:207) org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:206) org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:177) org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:230) org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:108) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)

In the IS, I have enabled all grant types, Implicit and Client credentials were tested to work fine. This error occurs only from 'password' grant type. Could someone let me know what I am doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this format to generate the token for password grant type.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Authorization: Basic <Base64Encoded(Consumer key:consumer secret)>, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://<host>:8243/token
```

Comment: the problem seemed more due to using email as user name without the SP1 patch.